# Unable to get PHP error reporting to work

Tags: php, wamp

I have checked php.ini and

```
log_errors = On
error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log" `
```

(the dir contain access.log, apache_error.log, log.dir, mysql.log)

there is no entry for "error_reporting" but there is a comment (which I did not quite understand)

```
; Eval the expression with current error_reporting().  Set to true if you want
; error_reporting(0) around the eval().
; http://php.net/assert.quiet-eval
;assert.quiet_eval = 0
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: `error_reporting()` is a function to be called from within your script.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set it at runtime:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: In *every* script?  Doesn't seem practical, especially if you'll be transitioning between development and production environments.

Comment: @GigaWatt: You do it one time in your bootstrap file, or any file that's included globally like a config file.

Comment: @GigaWatt Not in every script :P ^^ What Madmartigan said :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is another script setting error_reporting(0)?

Is your error log file writable?

In your php.ini (or as the other poster said in your script) set error_reporting = E_ALL

Are you generating errors?

Answer (score 0):

The following is in my php.ini file:

```
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
;   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

You should just be able to add the `error_reporting =` line to your php.ini file along with an appropriate value and be good to go.